# Converting Caffe layers with multiple nodes

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, caffe

I'm using caffe-tensorflow to convert a model.
I'm getting the error:

```
"Multiple top nodes are not supported"
```

I do have some layers inside the prototxt with multiple top nodes:

```
layer {
  name: "slice2"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "slice2_1"
  top: "slice2_2"
  slice_param {
    slice_dim: 1
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to do the conversion? (with or without caffe-tensorflow)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in caffe-tensorflow which only supports single top (output) nodes (see comments in graph.py).

Your alternatives are:

- clone the github code and add the functionality
- implement your model in Tensorflow code.